# Animating LinearLayout background to blink in Android

Tags: android, animation, android-linearlayout

The question is very simple but I can't manage to find a good solution to it. I have a LinearLayout in my activity. Depending on what the user does I need to make the background of my Layout blink 3 times. This means it will change the Background Color from transparent to Red and backwards for 3 times. Let me give you an example:

1. the user receives a question and 2 buttons with answers
2. the user presses the wrong answer. The layout containing the button will change it's background (Transparent - Red, Transparent - Red, Transparent - Red - Transparen) three times.

How can I make this in Android ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@vidstige: I have tried your suggestions but the background changing wasn't fluent, sometimes it worked sometimes only half sometimes it didn't

@Tim: your solution seems very good but I had some issues with it making it work and as I'm not really good at java I gave up.

The solution that works is a combination of principles of both answers. I'm not sure if it's the best one but works very good in my case

```
        Handler blinkHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                case 0:
                    lay1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        break;
                case 1:
                    lay1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    break;

                }
                super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };


    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
        Message msg = new Message();
         if(i % 2 == 0){
             msg.what = 0;
         }
        else{
            msg.what=1;
        }

        blinkHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, i*300);
    }
```

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Handler with the postDelayed method. That would look something like this:

```
    Handler h = new Handler();
    int count = 0;
    Runnable r=new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            if(count < 6){
                if(count % 2 == 0){
                    count++;
                    layout.setBackground(RED);
                    h.postDelayed(r,500);
                }else{
                    count++;
                    layout.setBackground(TRANSPARENT);
                    h.postDelayed(r,500);
                }
            }

        }

    };
    h.post(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) to schedule an action to change the background color using `View.setBackgroundColor(int color)` to red/transparent.

Using the `schedule(Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit unit)` method you can schedule all the color changes at once and they will be executed later in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

To make a color blink I remember there was a specific bit we used to set in C++ graphics library, in University days. I'm also trying to blink the background but I don't want to dedicate a thread for that purpose.

And if there's no alternate at all, I'll try to put a .gif image with alternating colors in the background.